# Hits Counter code error set cookie

Tags: php, cookies, counter

I have a PHP code for hits counter with cookies:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) {
    echo "not set";
    setcookie("visited",$id,time()+3600);
    mysql_query("UPDATE movie SET movie_views = ( movie_views + 1) WHERE id = $gid ");
}
```

Now the problem is that when I refresh the page, it counts 1 hit everytime and doesn't wait for 1 hour.

Comment: try use `print_r($_COOKIE);` to print out all cookies to test if it is setting the cookies correctly. You could also use `$_SESSION`?

Comment: `$_COOKIE` is needed to be delivered at client side. I'll suggest you to firstly `set` it and then `redirect` using `meta` to this code

Comment: All your doing is checking if it's set, there is no check to see if the cookie has the date

Comment: $gid = intval($_GET['id'])

Comment: @ogziii well, your code says `$id = intval(...`, not `$gid = intval(...`

Comment: $gid and $id , both exists

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirements are:

1) Someone visits your site with an ID of a record passed as part of the URL ($_GET).

a) IF they visit after some elapsed 'time interval' then the 'ID' is recorded.

b) If they have visited before and the 'time interval' has not expired then the request to record the 'id' is ignored.

The 'time interval' is recorded in a COOKIE called 'visited'.

You record the details in a database - i store the id in a $_SESSION variable. It is for demonstration only.

I show the method only. It is not meant to be efficient. It is designed to be debugged very easily. It reports every step and state.

I use a 'time interval' of 20 seconds.

I have a working example at: **[viper-7.com?id=9/](http://viper-7.com/XOOPNR?id=9)**. Note: the **$_GET[id] parameter** is passed on the **'viper-7' URL**! you can change it to ensure the code works. It will reject your new id until the 20 seconds have elapsed.

The code (it is commented):

```
<?php
session_start(); // Testing only - store last ID in $_SESSION['id']!

define ('VOTE_DELAY', '20'); // seconds

// show 'visited cookie or  if missing...
if (isset($_COOKIE['visted'])) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_COOKIE['visited']); // show all cookies currently active
    echo '</pre>';
}
else {
    echo '<br />No current $_COOKIE[visited] found!';
    echo '<br />';
}

// DEBUG - show current ID
echo '<br />Current Session ID: ', !empty($_SESSION['id']) ? $_SESSION['id'] : 'none';
echo '<br />';

// process whether visited in the last interval (20 seconds)
if (isset($_COOKIE['visited'])) {
    echo '<br />active Cookie: ', $_COOKIE['visited'],' - will leave now...';
    return; // no more voting until cookie expires
}

// no id provided - is error
if (empty($_GET['id'])) {
    echo '<br />no valid $_GET[id] provided : will leave - NO Visited Cookie set ';
    return; // do nothing
}

$id = $_GET['id']; // store new id in the session rather than the database

echo "<br />New VALID visit: will store cookie for: ", $id, ' in the $_SESSION[id] variable';
setcookie("visited", "$id", time() + VOTE_DELAY); // set the 'visited cookie
$_SESSION['id'] = $id; // store in session rather than the database.
//     mysql_query("UPDATE movie SET movie_views = ( movie_views + 1) WHERE id = $gid ");

echo "<br /> new cookie set...";
```

I have no idea why your code does not work.

Also, if the client deletes the 'visited' cookie then they can get the 'id' recorded as often as they wish. You will need to analyse the records in the database to ensure 'recordings of 'id' are valid.